# Is This an Interesting Principal Ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be a principal ideal in a commutative ring $R$, $x$ the generator of $I$, and $x^n\ne \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i,\, \forall a_i\in R\setminus I\bigcup\{0\},\, \forall n\in\mathbb N$. In other words, for this particular principal ideal, any integer power of the generator is assumed to not be expandable in its polynomial of lower orders with coefficients in the ring but not in the principal ideal. Is there a name and special interest in such an object? What are some of the interesting sufficient conditions that can achieve the aforementioned non-expandability condition?

Comment: I think you need more conditions on $a_i$, as letting some $a_i = 0$, some $a_i = x^m$ for some $m$ will mean this is true in all rings as $x^n = 0+0+\dots + x (x^{n-1})$.

Comment: @Mark: I think you may be confused about the non-expandability. It is a premise not a conclusion. I have changed the word description of the condition to make it clearer. On the other hand, I would welcome a (simple) sufficient (or even sufficient and necessary) condition that achieves the condition.

Comment: This condition will needs more limitation on the $a_i$s: given any $x\in R$, $x^2=a_1x$ where $a_1=x$.

Comment: @rschwieb: Could you please take a look at my response above to Mark? It is a constraint and thus part of the premise, not a conclusion drawn from the premise. It imposes the limitation but not NEED one.

Comment: @Hans I understand that it is a constraint. I'm saying that your constraint never holds for any principal ideal  in any ring, as written.

Comment: @rschwieb: Oh, yes. You and Mark are right. Thank you. I have edited the question. Please review.

Comment: If R is an integral domain then every principal ideal has this property.

Comment: @Hans do you have any particular ring $R$ in mind? Can your condition on $x^n$ not happen? Reducing $x^n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_ix^i$ mod $x^2$ gives $a_1 x \in x^2R$ (so $x$ would have to at least be a zero divisor).

Comment: @MarcBogaerts: Great. How do you show that? Note: I corrected a typo in the question: the summation starts from $0$ not $1$.

Comment: @AlexMacedo: For example, $R$ is the integer ring and $I$ generated by any non-integer fraction.

Comment: My comment dates from when the summation started at 1 then giving for $n = 2 $: $x^2 = a_1x \iff x(x-a_1) = 0$ which is impossible in an integral domain. But now we have that $x^2 = a_1x +a_0 \iff x(x-a_1) = a_0$, but the LHS is $\in I$  and the RHS $\in R \setminus  I$ (and this nonzero) so the condition is valid for all rings.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts: Excellent. I have edited again the condition, allowing the coefficients to take on $0$. So $R$ should be an integral domain, as you said before. If you would like to write the complete answer up, I will accept it. Thank you, Marc.

Comment: @hans A much more natural condition is when you restrict the $a_i$ to come from some subring of $R$. If $x$ failed your condition, it would be called algebraic over the subring.

Comment: @rschwieb: My condition requires the polynomial to be monic, while x being algebraic does not. But we can draw the coefficients from the field of fractions of $R$ if $R$ is an integral domain. Is that right?

Comment: @hans Well, that's my mistake because I was actually thinking of [integral elements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element) which are closely related. Check that one out (it uses mimic polynomials).

Comment: Monic, not mimic (autocorrected)

Comment: @rschwieb: I figured it was monic. Lol Integral elements is a good idea. It would be even better though if you can come up with a simpler condition that produces the conclusion that $x$ is not an integral element of the said subring. If you want to put that proposition up and elaborate it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $I$ be a principal ideal with $x$ s.t. $I = xR$. If $I$ does not have the property proposed in question, there exist the smallest natural number $n$ such that $a_i \in R$ and $x^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i \iff x^n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ix^i = x(x^{n-1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a_{i+1}x^i) = a_0$. Now $(...)\ne 0$ by $n$ being the smallest such natural number, together with $x\ne0$, we have $a_0\ne0$ as $R$ is an integral domain. But then the LHS $\in I$ and the RHS $\notin I$, a contradiction. The conclusion is that in an integral domain every principal ideal has the proposed property.

Comment: $(...)$ could be zero, which leads to the same argument but for a lower order polynomial. So there is an inductive argument missing. Do you agree?

Comment: @Hans and Marc Bogaerts: In an integral domain one can always chose $a_0\ne 0$.

Comment: @user26857: I do not understand your point. $a_0\ne 0$ would lead to, LHS not equal to RHS, a contradiction as stated in the answer.

Comment: @Hans Read again my comment.

Comment: @user26857: I agree with your comment per se. What I do not understand is how it is related to the answer. Could you please state explicitly and in detail your argument?

Comment: @Hans The answer doesn't need to consider the case $a_0=0$. This can be dismissed immediately by taking the smallest $n$ for such a relation takes place.

Comment: @user26857: You are right. Thank you. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Marc Bogaerts: I took the liberty of editing your answer per the comment of user26857 --- before I saw his suggestion that you do it. In this version, my previous suggestion becomes moot. If you do not like my edit, you certainly have the right to abandon it. I apologize in advance for my action which could be construed as rudeness.

Comment: @hans No problem, it's much cleaner now.